# terraform not creating lambda - Error: filename, s3_* or image_uri attributes must be set

Tags: lambda, terraform-provider-aws

terraform code i m using to create lambda:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_voting_backend" {
    description = ""
    function_name = "voting"
    handler = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
    architectures = [
        "x86_64"
    ]
    # s3_bucket = "prod-04-2014-tasks"
    # s3_key = "/snapshots/025416187662/voting-f2684d7f-4abb-4265-add7-edf4860adb28"
    # s3_object_version = "ZmtZwWWuw5iTqOyFk6YakhAeTTowkj5E"

    memory_size = 128
    role = "${aws_iam_role.voting_iam_lambda_role.arn}"
    runtime = "python3.9"
    timeout = 3
    tracing_config {
        mode = "PassThrough"
    }

}
```

the error it gives:

```
Error: filename, s3_* or image_uri attributes must be set│
│   with aws_lambda_function.lambda_voting_backend,
```

i commented it out in lambda terraform code above, what to put for s3_ attr to make it work?

default region is us-east-2 for this tf code above, however when i tried to uncomment and run with all these s3_ attributes and it gives error of wrong region( i did create manually that lambda function in us-east-1). the error it gives is about region mismatch:

```
Error: error creating Lambda Function (1): InvalidParameterValueException: Error occurred while GetObjectVersion. S3 Error Code: PermanentRedirect. S3 Error Message: The bucket is in this region: us-east-1. Please use this region to retry the request
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "1c726849-9795-4bad-b7bc-d02f8987f32e"
│   },
│   Message_: "Error occurred while GetObjectVersion. S3 Error Code: PermanentRedirect. S3 Error Message: The bucket is
in this region: us-east-1. Please use this region to retry the request",
│   Type: "User"
│ }
```

i did not create this s3_object_version and dont know where it comes from.

Comment: you can use [aws_s3_object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object) to specify you `s3` resource.

Comment: @Sajjad, i did not even notice any other buckets that were created for my lambda, strange. should i create explicitly some s3 bucket for my lambda?

Comment: Before trying to create a bucket, maybe check in which region terraform is trying to create the lambda. If you are using an existing bucket then it should reside in the same region.